Outlook Add-in: How to get information about selected folder
I am developing a web-based outlook add-in. I would like to connect external information to user created outlook folders by keeping the folder id stored on my own database. For this approach to work i would need to get what folder has the user clicked from outlook.
I have subscribed to item change event like this:
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.ItemChanged,
            handleSelectedItemChange
        );

I get the selected item like this:
export const readItem = async (): Promise<Email> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
            Office.context.mailbox.item;
            if (!item || !item.body || !item.body.getAsync) {
                console.log("Error reading mail", item);
                return reject("Error reading mail.");
            }
            item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, (res) => {
                const body = res.value;
                resolve({
                    body,
                    subject: item.subject /* or normalizedSubject */,
                    base: item,
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};

I get the item correctly when i click an email. When i select the folder the item i undefined. I know the item type supports only appointments and messages.
Is there any other way to get selected folder info like different event type or completely different way?
